# Turning up built-in speakers in Ubuntu

Tags: dell, speakers

I am wondering how to turn on the built-in speaker DELL Optiplex 990 in Ubuntu.

[image: sound settings screenshot]

Comment: I am using a 980 to type this, and I am pretty sure the internal speakers come on if I pulled out the 3.5mm external cable that goes to my speakers, and only then.  Maybe the 990 is different, but the dell 980's speakers were pretty poor (*very tinny*) so I never cared about loosing them.  `pavucontrol` lists mine as unavailable.

Comment: Have you tried using pavucontrol? That should easily allow you to play sound over speakers, and make it go above 100% (a bad idea generally, because of how bad the sound distorts)

Comment: Hi, I am not able to install pavucontrol. Here is command reply. `user---:~$ sudo apt install pavucontrol-qt 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pavucontrol-qt
`

Comment: @DomoNCar he already has that option as you can see in the screen shot.

Comment: @engr_john you ubuntu is already on max but applications (webbrowsers with youtube running inside them, or Rythmbox for music, or VLC for movies) have their own, compleltely seperate, volume lever. You'll have to turn up the volume there too ...By default they all start at half-strength. But in any even, your computer tower : https://www.portables.org/smartblog/27_test-complet-dell-optiplex-990.html is equipped with absolutely garbage onboard speakers. you can't get a disco going in your house using your PC, sorry. why not ask if anyone arround you wants to give their sound system away?

Comment: @engr_john [`pavucontrol-qt`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pavucontrol-qt) is available in the Universe repository. See [How do I enable the “Universe” repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)